# Set HTML tag to 100% height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to set 100% of height to a HTML element.
On mobile, this div will go under the .div_left div, and the floating will be cleared.

I have these divs on my theme:

```
<div class="col-md-7 div_left"></div>
<div class="col-md-5 div_right"></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

I give them this css: (global bootstrap.css also included)

```
.div_left{ background:#fff; padding:40px;}
.div_right{ background:#ccc; padding:40px; height:100%;}
```

I tryed `height:100vh;` but that's not working, when the page has to many content, and I can scroll it vertically.

I also tryed `min-height:100%` but that didn't work. I can see the right div gray background, but that's just because it has padding.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBJJ4.png)

Second try:
[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksasH.png)

Comment: Could you clarify your question ? Show us what it looks like right now and what you want it to look like for example ?

Comment: Please clean up to HTML and provide enough to repro the issue. And why don't you use `min-height:100vh`?

Comment: I writed, that why 100vh isnt working.

Comment: You said `height:100vh` and `min-height:100%` wasn't working, *not* **`min-height:100vh`**. Please clarify the question and exactly what you've tried. Also what exactly does *"when the page has to many content, and i can scroll it vertically"* mean? What is the expected behavior? Will the extra content be hidden and not accessible? Do you expect the scroll bar somewhere else?

Comment: I added an image to the post. You can see on it, that i have to many content, and i scrolled down the site. When i scroll, the gray background will end, thats why 100vh isnt working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use min-height 100vh on the entire row...

```
.div_left{ background:#fff; padding:40px;}
.div_right{ background:#ccc; padding:40px;}

.mvh-100 {
    min-height: 100vh;   
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/vTYz8XE6cG

Desktop:

[image]

Mobile:

[image]

Comment: No. I added an image to the post, with second name. Thats what your code does, i copied it to my file.

Comment: No, that's not what the code does.  Look at the demo. You're not clarifying exactly what is expected. If it's not working you have other CSS or HTML that's effecting the layout.

Comment: In the html, the divs have flex- classes. Where are these added in the css?

Comment: They're part of Bootstrap, but they're not required for `min-height:100vh` to work. You'll see the demo also works fine w/o those, but they could be used to change the desktop vs mobile layout. But since you haven't clarified what to expect it's all guesswork.

Comment: Now i see, i added display:flex to the mv-100 class. Now, the height isfine, but the divs are floating in mobile view, they dont go under each other.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3 or Bootstrap 4?

Comment: Well, thats a good question, because when i compressed the css file, it removed all comment. But, i think, its the version 3.

Comment: Well that explains the problem. There are many other questions on SO that already address this and please make sure you properly tag questions in the future.

Comment: Yes, now i understand it. But whats missing from the 3?

Answer (score 0):

To use `height:100%;` a parent element should have a `height: fixedHeight;` because that it's not working for you.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp

> % Defines the height in percent of the containing block

What you need to define is: 100% of what?

Here's more information about `vh`

[Make a div 100% height of the browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window)

There says:

> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.